# Win 7 firewall won't turn on, nor the McAfee firewall. Hit by "Win 7 Anti-virus 2012" trojan. Removed, but a downed firewall is a lasting legacy

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, firewall, trojan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

I caught the Trojan right away, I think, but both my McAfee & Win 7 (x64) firewalls are not able to be engaged/turned on now. MS Error Code 0x80070424 when attempting to turn on Win 7 firewall. No viruses. Swept it with McAfee AV, Malwarebytes Anti-Malware, Microsoft malware removal tools. Followed Microsoft's three courses of alternative actions they posted for instructions for getting the Win 7 firewall back up and on. Nothing. Same error code. The post just said see MS support if those fixes failed.

So I removed McAfee altogether. Still Win 7 (professional version) firewall won't come on; and clean of detectable bugs.

And I'm fully updated with MS Windows 7 updates as well, which is no longer automatic, that too a legacy of the trojan bug I think. Any thoughts on how to get the Win 7 firewall operational??? And auto updating reengaged?

Comment: These may or may not help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811259

Comment: honestly, unless there's some compelling reason not to, wiping the system is the best solution

Comment: Agreed. The chances are some system level files are broken or missing.  W7 doesn't have a repair-install so starting over is the best bet.  Nuking it from orbit is the only way to be sure.

Comment: a simple google search provides [this](https://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2011/12/27/error-code-0x80070424-with-windows-firewall-and-quot-base-filtering-engine-service-quot-not-available-in-services-database-list.aspx?Redirected=true)

Answer (score 1):

I would give [TDSSKILLER](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208280684) a go. You may still have a rootkit.